# a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int" in CPP

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to solve this question that was asked for me, And I'm very close on finding it by running the code, but I cannot because I get this C++ error message: `a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int"`

*Let Q be an instance of an ADT per Row. Q.enqueue (x) adds an element x
in a row. Q.dequeue () performs the subtraction operation in the row and returns the removed value.
Consider the following code snippet:*

[image: codepseudo]

*Demonstrate the execution of this code by showing the state of Queue. Which will
be the value of the variable count, when the execution of the above code is completed?*

C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    queue<int> myqueue;
    int count = 1;
    int x;
    myqueue.push(1);
    do{
        count=count+1;
        x = myqueue.pop();
        myqueue.push( 2*x );
        myqueue.push( 2*x+1);
    } while(x != 967);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One particular problem with this code is that the `myqueue.pop()` does not return anything. You will have to fetch from the `myqueue` first, and then [pop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop) this element.

You should consider getting familiar with the [members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue#Member_functions) of the `std::queue`. In particular, the `back()`, which provides access the last element.

Comment: Other thing to note is that it is not promised that it will ever be so that `x == 967`, means that the loop might run indefinitely (which it does). Consider introducing less strict `<` relation.

Comment: @rawrex: Nope, the values for x in the loop are the integes 1,2,3,... so this definitely terminates. See the anwer of molbdnilo

Comment: @NordicMainframe now I see it. My mistake was in making (assuming) essentially a stack out of the queue, by calling `back()`, not `front()`. *In which case, it gave me powers of 2 minus one for `x`, a sequence that's never even close to the `967`*. Thank you for input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation error is caused by the fact that `pop` does not return anything – you need to use `front` first, then `pop`.

However, this is not what you're supposed to do; you are supposed to solve this by thinking and understanding how a queue works.

Start with the first task: "Demonstrate the execution of this code by showing the state of Queue."

These are the first few states of the queue:

```
1
2 3
3 4 5
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8 9
6 7 8 9 10 11
7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

And now you can see a pretty obvious relationship between `count` and the front of the queue.

Comment: top()? you mean front()?

Comment: @NordicMainframe Indeed. I was thinking of stacks.

Comment: @molbdnilo so what the count will be?

Comment: @neyeror358 Write down what `count` is on each iteration. Compare to the value at the front of the queue.